# How to make jQuery Shout Box

Tags: jquery, ajax

A week before I asked on SO how to get started to make a shout box in ASP.NET then I received response to use AJAX updatepanel, triggers and timer.

Well, I followed everything and I built my own shoutbox. The problem is when even I send message on shoutbox on the other side the message is getting added to the receiver's updatepanel but the updatepanel is not scrolling down on each update.

I searched for this issue in search engines and posted at SO but didn't find any working answer except a suggestion that using jQuery to make a shoutbox is more powerful than AJAX.

So, I decided to move to jQuery.

Can anybody tell me how to get started to make a shoutbox using ASP.NET & jQuery.

Please do not give me a link to download a sample of such project. I want to make my own script.

Please tell me what should I use in jQuery instead of updatepanel, timer, triggers etc to make a shoutbox.

Comment: "Wanna" is not a word, please stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

May be jQuery scrollTo plugin will be useful http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo
After new message is added use this plugin to scroll your shoutbox to last message.

Comment: But client side scrolling is working fine where server side scrolling is not working :( Please read the question once again.